# RESTful API not recieving POST from AJAX button

Tags: php, ajax

I have an AJAX button to like the post, which sends JSON to a RESTful API to execute all my backend code. 
From my troubleshooting, it seems like the AJAX button isn't even sending the POST request to the API, but I could be wrong. I have tried a few things to get a response back from the AJAX request.. but I never get anything in my console.log.

I'm following a YouTube tutorial series and even tried copying and pasting the tutorials code from GitHub, but I'm still getting nothing in console.log.

---

So my 'like' button has a data-id field, which the AJAX listens out for. The code for the button is...

```
<div><button class="btn btn-primary"  data-id="'+posts[index].PostID+'" type="button" id="InteractButt" style="background-image: url(&quot;assets/img/Thumbs%20Up.png&quot;);"></button> // Code for displaying amount
```

My AJAX request is listening out for data-id buttons...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('[data-id]').click(function() {
             var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-id');
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "api/likes?id=" + $(this).attr('data-id'),
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: '',
                        success: function(r) {
                        var res = JSON.parse(r)
                        console.log(r)
                        // $("[data-id='"+buttonid+"']").html(' <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" data-aos="flip-right"></i><span> '+res.Likes+' Likes</span>')
                       },
                        error: function(r) {
                        console.log(r)
                                            }
                        });
                    }); 
     </script>
```

And my API is waiting to action this code;

```
        else if ($_GET['url'] == "likes") {
        $postId = $_GET['id'];
                $likerId = Login::isLoggedIn();
                // code to sort out liked.. then reply with the count in JSON
                echo "{";
                echo '"Likes":';
                echo $db->query('SELECT likes FROM posts WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$postId))[0]['likes'];
                echo "}";
        }
```

Comment: Have you watched the request/response in the developer's tools of the browser?

Comment: Are you getting anything from the network tab in the developer console?  Specifically Headers sent and Response

Comment: The AJAX request uses POST but the API uses GET.

Comment: I'm not getting anything in the network tab. No new requests...

It looks like AJAX isn't even sending anything?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sending a POST request to your server prevents you from accessing your query strings via GET in php. Just change your type to a GET and you're good, and if it still doesn't work then also change your content-type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "application/json":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#InteractButt').click(function() {
         // console.log('hello'); just to make sure somethin happens when you click...
         var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "api/likes?id=" + $(this).attr('data-id'),
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: '',
                    success: function(r) {
                    var res = JSON.parse(r)
                    console.log(r)
                    // $("[data-id='"+buttonid+"']").html(' <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" data-aos="flip-right"></i><span> '+res.Likes+' Likes</span>')
                   },
                    error: function(r) {
                    console.log(r)
                                        }
                    });
                }); 
 </script>
```

Hope it works out...!

UPDATE

Ill just implement what I would try to do

```
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary"  data-id="posts[index].PostID" type="button" id="InteractButt" style="background-image: url(&quot;assets/img/Thumbs%20Up.png&quot;);"></button>
</div>
<script>
$('#InteractButt').on('click', function(){
  var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $.post('api/likes', { 'buttonid': buttonid }, function(data, xhr, status){
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
  }
}
</script>
```

and my php would look like...

```
$postid = $_POST['buttonid'];
```

Comment: try change your selector to $('#InteractButt') instead of $('[data-id]')...maybe you click listener isnt working

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a post request by AJAX. You don't need to send **id** of the post with a GET parameter. You can just grab the id at the api side with $_POST.

Use Jquery's FormData to send id to your api as a *data* like this.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', $(this).attr('data-id'))

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "api/likes",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(r) {
        var res = JSON.parse(r)
        console.log(r)
    },
    error: function(r) {
        console.log(r)
    });
});
```

And grab the data at the API end like this.

```
$postId = $_POST['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I've been so stupid, and I really don't want to admit to this but I fixed the issue, and on the off chance someone else get's stuck...

My AJAX listener had to be within the foreach loop while generating posts. I had it as a separate script at the bottom of the page...

I'm learning...